# python download xls javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to download an .xls file from a page such as this through a POST request and I've tried using urllib2, requests, etc. but I think the file is accessed through a javascript function.

My code is:

```
import urllib2

url= 'http://www.inegi.org.mx/est/contenidos/espanol/proyectos/censos/ce2009/saic/exportar.asp?Cuadro=INEGI.+Censos+Econ%C3%B3micos+2009.+Resultados+definitivos&Censo=2009&Nacional=&vcampo=H001A&Sector=23&c=17166&Genera=1&formato=Hoja+de+C%C3%A1lculo+Excel%28.xls%29&Modelo=SCIAN&Grupo=AA&Municipio=01001'
obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
file = '/home/j/Dropbox/School/RA/download.xls'
output = open(file, 'wb')
output.write(obj.read())
output.close()
```

Doesn't seem to give me what I want. I know that on the page using firebug, the javascript function
    document.exporta.submit()
generates the .xls file, but I have no idea how to save it using python. I've searched just about everywhere to no avail. Thanks so much!